# How to implement CV_MAT_ELEM( mat, elemtype, row, col ) in OpenCv4Android?

Tags: android, opencv

i am trying to port OpenCv C++ code for Camera Calibration to Android. 
While writing the intrensic and extrensic matrix, i am stuck up at java method for the OpenCv function in C++ **CV_MAT_ELEM( mat, elemtype, row, col )**, which allows us to access the individual elements of a 2-dimentional multichannel image.

Please help me out, as i am successfully able to port the rest of the code, just stuck over here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already checked the documentation, couldn't find the alternative to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer from the following link - http://answers.opencv.org/question/5/how-to-get-and-modify-the-pixel-of-mat-in-java/